# Oracle parameter with Dapper issue

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-web-api, dapper

I am struggling with using ORACLE parameters via DAPPER. The error message received is "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist".

However the code works without the parameter, and I suspect that this is a simple Oracle parameter syntax issue. The code follows:

```
    public List<ForecastData>GetByFiscalYear(string fiscalYear)
    {
        List<ForecastData> queryResults = new List<ForecastData>();

        String sqlQuery = @"SELECT RES.FISCALYEAR year FROM RESOURCE_AVAILABILITY RES WHERE RES.FISCALYEAR = :p_fiscalYear";

        using (var oraCon = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Oracle_HRZD"].ToString()))
        {
            oraCon.Open();
            queryResults = oraCon.Query<ForecastData>(sqlQuery, new { p_fiscalYear = fiscalYear }).ToList();
        }

        return new List<ForecastData>(queryResults);
    }
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Your select statement seems to be pretty wrong. Do you mean: _SELECT RES.FISCALYEAR FROM RES WHERE RES.FISCALYEAR = :p_fiscalYear";_

Comment: The query uses column name alias and runs successfully when the parameter is removed. My question is regarding the Oracle parameter.

Comment: The error complains about the table name, not the parameter. Are you able to run the query if you hard-code the year value?

Comment: Have you tried to explicitely add the schema to the query? `Select x from schema.resouce_availability`?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, ORA-00942 is exactly what it says, it can't find the table/view (RESOURCE_AVAILABILITY) you are selecting from. So it's not in the schema for the user you log on as or the user has not been granted SELECT on the table/view if it's another schema.

But you say that if you remove `WHERE RES.FISCAL_YEAR :p_fiscalyear`, then it works. So it seems like you have select permissions on the table. Do you mean remove the whole where selection or have you tested enter a fixed string, as in `WHERE RES.FISCAL_YEAR='2016'`?

My other top tip is to run Wireshark and look at what really is sent to the database, usually you connect on port 1521 filter on that.

Comment: Whoever downvoted should know that Oracle **doesn't** reply with `Access Denied` if the user doesn't have permissions. If someone doesn't have permission to access a table or view, the error will say that the table is missing

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to use the fully-qualified database-object name, including the schema. Thanks for your assistance.